# i18n translation make a variable in bold

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation, react-i18next

i am trying to make a variable in that is in the middle of the translation string in  but i could not found a solution.
I need all my translations in 2 different languages: 'en' and 'de'

**My code looks like this:**

`import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'`

`const { t } = useTranslation('payment');`

`const companyName = 'Probando'`

`<Typography>{ t('setup with company name', <b>{companyName: companyName}</b>)</Typography>`

**My translation file:**

payment en.json
`{ "setup with company name": "Please contact {{ companyName }} to re-edit or re-send this invitation.", }`

payment de.json:
`{ "setup with company name": "Bitte wenden Sie sich an {{ companyName }} um diese Einladung nochmal zu bearbeiten oder neu zu erhalten." }`

Answer (score 4):

you need to use the `Trans` component if you want to use tags inside the translation.

https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

```js
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next'

const { t } = useTranslation('payment');

<Trans t={t} i18nKey="setup with company name">
  Please contact <b>{{ companyName }}</b> to re-edit or re-send this invitation.
</Trans>
```

and then the translation like this:

```
// EN
"setup with company name": "Please contact <1>{{companyName}}</1> to re-edit or re-send this invitation.",

// DE
"setup with company name": "Bitte wenden Sie sich an <1>{{ companyName }}</1> um diese Einladung nochmal zu bearbeiten oder neu zu erhalten."
```

Comment: Thank you very much! my question now is  how do i do with the other translation that i need? becasue that is gonna translate just in  english but i also need the german one. Thanks

Comment: like in the example i posted, you use <1> instead of <b> for translation.

Comment: PS: Am besten du verwendest ein Tool um die translations zu extrahieren. Infos dazu findest du hier: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/extracting-translations. dann musst du nicht auswendig wissen welche Nummer (<1>) du hier verwenden musst.

Comment: but only renders the english version because we are setting the english text: 
<Trans i18nKey="setup with company name">
  Please contact <b>{{ companyName }}</b> to re-edit or re-send this invitation.
</Trans>

I need something like this for the german one?: 
<Trans i18nKey="setup with company name">
  Bitte wenden Sie sich an <b>{{ companyName }}</b>  um diese Einladung nochmal zu bearbeiten oder neu zu erhalten.
</Trans>`

Comment: no, it will replace the content inside the `Trans` component with the text from the translation file. if you set your translation to German it will use the text defined in the german translation. The text inside the component is only the default translation.

Comment: ah you use `const { t } = useTranslation('payment');` i overlocked this:
you need to use `<Trans t={t} ...` and pass the right trans instance (`t`) here. otherwise it will look in the default translations, where the key for translation is not set. i will update my answer.

Comment: Now is working   that was the missing part t={ t } !! Thank you so much